# I cannot print delete_first result in C (circular linkedlist)

Tags: c, circular-list

I want to print delete_first result and delete_last result. But it can only print delete_last code. How can i solve this matter?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int element;
typedef struct ListNode {
    element data;
    struct ListNode* link;
} ListNode;

void print_list(ListNode* head)
{
    ListNode* p;

    if (head == NULL) return;
    else {
        p = head->link;
        do {
            printf("%d ", p->data);
            p = p->link;
        } while (p != head->link);
    }printf("\n");
}




ListNode* insert_first(ListNode* head, element data)
{
    ListNode* node = (ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    node->data = data;
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = node;
        node->link = head;
    }
    else {
        node->link = head->link;
        head->link = node;
    }
    return head;
}

ListNode* insert_last(ListNode* head, element data)
{
    ListNode* node = (ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    node->data = data;
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = node;
        node->link = head;
    }
    else {
        node->link = head->link;
        head->link = node;
        head = node;
    }
    return head;
    }
```

I want to print delete_first result and delete_last result. But I can only print delete_last result. How can i print delete_first result?

This is my delete_first code.

```
  ListNode* delete_first(ListNode* head) {
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            return head;
        }
        if (head->link == head) {
            free(head);
            head = NULL;
            return head;
        }
        ListNode* p = head->link;
        head->link = p->link;
        free(head);
        head = NULL;
        return head;
    }



    ListNode* delete_last(ListNode* head) {
        if (head == NULL)
            return head;
        ListNode* p = head->link;
        if (head->link == head) {
            free(head);
            head = NULL;
            return head;
        }
        while (p->link != head) {
            p = p->link;
        }
        p->link = head->link;
        free(head);
        head = p;
        return head;
    }

int main() {
    ListNode* head = NULL;

    head = insert_first(head, 10);
    head = insert_first(head, 20);
    head = insert_first(head, 30);
    head = insert_first(head, 40);
    head = insert_last(head, 50);
    print_list(head);

    
    head=delete_last(head);
    print_list(head);
    
    head = delete_first(head);
    print_list(head);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to give us more details. What is the problem with the program as you show it? You are calling `print_list(head)` after `delete_first(head)`, what is the problem that gives you? Doesn't it print anything at all? Do you get the wrong list? Do you get a crash? Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I also recommend you learn how to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your programs. For example use a debugger to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. At the same time use pencil and paper to visualize the statements and what the code is doing. Draw boxes for nodes and variables, and arrows for pointers and links. Erase and redraw pointers as you change them.

Comment: You always return `NULL` from `delete_first`. Maybe you are missing the line `head = p;` that you use in `delete_last`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the element being removed, then you cannot `free()` it, or you have to copy it to a local variable and return it by value.

If you want caller to be able to print what remains of the list, then you need to find the `last` node which has a `link` that points at `head` and have it point at `head->next` instead.  Then return that value (instead of NULL):

```
ListNode* delete_first(ListNode* head) {
    if(!head)
       return NULL;
    if(head == head->link) {
       free(head);
       return NULL;
    }
    ListNode* last;
    for(last = head; last->link != head; last = last->link);
    last->link = head->link;
    free(head);
    return last->link;
}
```

There is no point of setting `head = NULL` as the copy of that variable is lost the caller anyways.